# Define Custom Page

Tags: environments

How do I define environment such that:

It will start a new page; it will be followed by a new page; it will have a custom page color and font color.

Comment: `\newenvroment{SpecialPage}{\clearpage\pagecolor{yellow!20!white}\color{blue}}{\clearpage}` and use `\begin{SpecialPage}some text here\end{SpecialPage} . Requires package `xcolor`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why do I get error because of `\clearpage` (also tried `\newpage`)?

Comment: No idea, i just declared the code to be working. I haven't actually tested it. Can you show us a minimal working example to reproduce the (yet unknown) error?

Comment: @blackened Apart from typos and the missing `\pagecolor{white}` after the `\clearpage` in the “end” part, the code works.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I think, the copy-paste induced some character problem. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: @egreg Confirmed. It was an U+200B problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code works :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{SpecialPage}
{\clearpage\pagecolor{yellow!20!white}\color{blue}}{\clearpage\pagecolor{white}}
\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{SpecialPage}
Some text.
\end{SpecialPage}

Some text.

\end{document}
```